# Wordpress Meta Box plugin, "Fatal Error: Call to undefined method"

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

Huge issue with this plugin!!!!

I updated Wordpress and everything and now I have this error so I can't edit some Wordpress pages:

“**Fatal error: Call to undefined method RW_Meta_Box::get_class_name() in /home/wwwrcf/public_html/wp-content/plugins/meta-box-group/class-rwmb-group-field.php on line 63**”

```
public static function html( $meta, $field )
{
    ob_start();

    // Add filter to child field meta value, make sure it's added only once
    if ( empty( self::$meta_queue ) )
    {
        add_filter( 'rwmb_field_meta', array( __CLASS__, 'child_field_meta' ), 10, 3 );
    }

    // Add group value to the queue
    array_unshift( self::$meta_queue, $meta );

    // Add clone index to make sure each child field has an unique ID.
    $clone_index = '';
    if ( $field['clone'] && preg_match( '|_\d+$|', $field['id'], $match ) )
    {
        $clone_index = $match[0];
    }

    foreach ( $field['fields'] as $child_field )
    {
        $child_field['field_name']       = self::child_field_name( $field['field_name'], $child_field['field_name'] );
        $child_field['attributes']['id'] = ( isset( $child_field['attributes']['id'] ) ? $child_field['attributes']['id'] : $child_field['id'] ) . $clone_index;
****line 63 -> call_user_func( array( RW_Meta_Box::get_class_name( $child_field ), 'show' ), $child_field, RWMB_Group::$saved );
    }

    // Remove group value from the queue
    array_shift( self::$meta_queue );

    // Remove filter to child field meta value and reset class's parent field's meta
    if ( empty( self::$meta_queue ) )
    {
        remove_filter( 'rwmb_field_meta', array( __CLASS__, 'child_field_meta' ) );
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Need to fix this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Disable the meta box plugin via admin, or delete the plugin folder wp-content/plugins/meta-box-group

Comment: @VinnieJames works for me!!! Thanks for the solution!!! :)